# How to remove 'u'(unicode) from a dictionary item

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to convert dictionary item into a list ,But the dictionary item contains 'u' which is to be removed.
Ex: dictionary={u'test1': u'test1value', u'test2': u'test2value'} 
I have used

```
f = dictionary
output_list = f.items()
return output_list
```

and output_list contains (u'test1', u'test1value') ,(u'test2',u'test2value')

->But, I am expecting out_list as ('test1', 'test1value') ,('test2','test2value) So that I can compare these values with other item.
Please provide any help on this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get the u"xyz" format when I print a list of unicode strings in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180929/why-do-i-get-the-uxyz-format-when-i-print-a-list-of-unicode-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean. You can still compare these specific unicode strings to ASCII strings:

```
>>> u_foo = u'foo'
>>> foo = 'foo'
>>> u_foo == foo
True
```

If somehow you can't, try encoding the string into a different charset first.